# How can I update a PHP page without refreshing

Tags: php, web

I am trying to add some new comments when a user presses the more comments button. However, the page keeps refreshing whenever the button is pressed. I want to add new comments to the page without having it refresh each time.

here is the comment code part:

```html
                    <?php
                        $num = count($com_elements[0]);
                        if(isset($_POST['number'])){$num_lim = $_POST['number'];}else{$num_lim = 2;}
                        if (isset($_POST['more_comments']) && $num_lim < $num) {
                            $num_lim = $num_lim + 1;
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php if(isset($com_elements)):?>
                        <?php for ($i=0; $i < $num_lim; $i++):?>
                            <div id="comment_bar" class="mb-5">
                                <div class="card border-light shadow-sm">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 name="username"><?php echo username_grabber($com_elements[1][$i],$con);?></h5>
                                        <hr>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="card-text">
                                        <p><?php echo $com_elements[3][$i];?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor?>
                        <div>
                            <form method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php if(isset($num_lim)){echo $num_lim;}else{echo 2;};?>">
                                <button name="more_comments" id="more_comments" class="form-control border-light">More comments</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif?>
```

Note: I am a beginner in PHP and I know this method might not be productive.

Comment: you have to use ajax to parse data from PHP to JS

Comment: is this the only way ? @RomanGavrilov

Comment: you could add the users comment to the dom with some basic js, if you want other users comments, you need to either use ajax, server-sent events or websocket

Comment: The answer is through Javascript, also, since you are using a form each click on the button in the form will post which will cause reload. in JS you will be able to preventDefault and retrieve the data to the console and or update the correct div with more comments - children. PHP alone does not support this - it is a server language.., you request and receive response from the server, a new request , new response.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not the client. The only two ways to get new PHP data on the page are either a full page refresh, or using Javascript to make the AJAX/XHR request in the background and do the update to the browser content.

Comment: Thank you so much that was so helpful @Shlomtzion

Comment: That was so helpful thank you @Sammitch